# Is it possible to generalize query patterns in repository class?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

My question may be a little harder to get at first, so I want to start with an example. Given this repository example:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "movies", path = "movies")
public interface MovieRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Movie, Long> {

    Movie findByTitle(@Param("title") String title);

    Collection<Movie> findByTitleLike(@Param("title") String title);

    @Query("MATCH (m:Movie)<-[r:ACTED_IN]-(a:Person) RETURN m,r,a LIMIT {limit}")
    Collection<Movie> graph(@Param("limit") int limit);
}
```

I can post 3 types of questions by sending parameter "title" and "limit". However, in my application, users' questions may be too diverse so if I follow this pattern in the example, I would need to create numerous interface methods like this example to query on the graph, each with a @Query annotation to answer a specific question. Because my domain is large, entities, attributes and relationships are a lot.

Is there a more generalized way to create the annotated methods with @Query to potentially answer a very diverse set of questions? My goal is to create as few as possible those methods to fulfill the needs from as many as possible questions.

Comment: Did you check [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)?